# How to get a date info out of a string and then capture the earliest results by subject by test

Tags: r, date

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

[image]

I want t o build some variables to capture the earliest date for each test and its scores. I need to date infor out of variable `Time`. and then capture the date for each test. for test results, if there are two same test were done in the same date with score `a` and `b`, then record it as `a+b`. The result that I want is sth that looks like this:

[image]

I stuck at the first place which is getting the date info out of `Time`.

My codes are:

```
df1$date<- as.Date(df1$Time, format = "%Y-%B-%dT%H:%M")
```

It gave me NA for all of them.
I plan to use `group_by(ID, test)` `... date==min(date),` etc.

what should I do? Could anyone one give me some guidance on this?

Sample data can be build using codes :

```
df<-structure(list(ID = structure(c("C5-102", "C5-102", "C5-102", 
"C5-102", "C5-102", "C5-102", "C5-102", "C5-102", "C5-102", "C5-102", 
"C1-103", "C1-103", "C1-103", "C1-103", "C1-103", "C1-103", "C1-103", 
"C1-103", "C8-104", "C8-104", "C8-104", "C8-104", "C8-104", "C8-104"
), label = "Unique Subject Identifier", format.sas = "$"), score = c(73.8, 
100, 147.6, 73.8, 147.6, 73.8, 147.6, 1600, 1600, 1600, 64.5, 
129, 64.5, 129, 64.5, 129, 4302, 86, 62.7, 125.4, 62.7, 125.4, 
62.7, 125.4), test = c("A", "M", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", 
"C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "M", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A"), Time = c("2016-03-16T10:22", "2016-03-25T01:23", 
"2016-03-16T11:10", "2016-03-17T12:12", "2016-03-17T12:52", "2016-03-18T12:05", 
"2016-03-18T12:53", "2016-03-21T11:00", "2016-03-22T11:55", "2016-03-23T12:34", 
"2016-08-09T14:13", "2016-08-09T14:49", "2016-08-10T13:30", "2016-08-10T14:30", 
"2016-08-12T13:35", "2016-08-12T14:20", "2016-08-14T13:00", "2016-08-18T01:00", 
"2016-08-11T14:38", "2016-08-11T15:42", "2016-08-12T14:22", "2016-08-12T15:26", 
"2016-08-13T14:31", "2016-08-13T15:45")), row.names = c(NA, -24L
), label = "EX                              ", class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Many thanks and happy holiday!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pivot_wider` after creating the columns grouped by 'ID' and 'test'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
out <- df %>%
   mutate(Date = as.Date(Time)) %>% 
   group_by(ID, test) %>%
   mutate(time = as.Date(max(Date)),
          level = str_c(score[Time == max(Date)], collapse="+")) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = test, values_from = c(time, level))
```

Comment: for level, is it possible to get `a+b` as characters in stead of number?

Comment: Amazed by `pivot_wider`. Thanks for introduce that. Happy holiday!

Comment: Just curious , why `df$date<- as.Date(df$Time, format = "%Y-%B-%dT%H:%M")` won't work? Did I summarized `format` wrong?

Comment: @Stataq Your Time column format is `2016-03-16T10:22` i.e. it would be `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M`

Comment: @Stataq Also, for this case, you don't need the format, because the `as.Date` is checking only for the Date part which is in the correct format i.e. `as.Date(df$Time)#
 [1] "2016-03-16" ..`

Comment: @Stataq Also shorter format version would be `as.Date(df$Time, format = "%FT%H:%M")`. Note that if it was `%H:%M%S`, you could have used `as.Date(df$Time, format = "%FT%T")`